# Double tap UISearchBar with search delegate on iOS 7 causes UISearchBar to disappear

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

We have a search bar in the table header.  When the user taps on it twice quickly on iOS 7, it disappears.  Does anyone have any suggestions what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Is it going under Nav bar? I have search bar on few views and works fine.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. I have tried by removing following lines from code. 
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
It solves the issue. But the UI gets disturb.

Answer (score 9):

After lots of trial and errors, I found that when searchDisplayController ends search, searchbar gets disappear, so I have reinserted the searchbar to table header and it worked for me.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.searchingFetchedResultsController = nil;
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        [self.tableView insertSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar aboveSubview:self.tableView];
    }
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got the same bug too.

Comment: thanks Priya, that seems to work so basically:                        - (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    if (IS_IOS7_OR_GREATER) {
        [self.tableView insertSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar aboveSubview:self.tableView];
    }
}

Comment: Surprisingly it really helped, however dirty the solution is and I really don't like that I have to use it as well. The issue arises when user taps again into the already-animating search view, where the other tap is received by empty results table of the searchDisplayController – causing it to close immediately.

Answer (score 7):

(I posted this same answer to [Troubles with UISearchBar \ UISearchDisplayViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965713/troubles-with-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplayviewcontroller), which seems like a duplicate of this question.)

I encountered the same issue, and noticed that `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` was being called twice. The first time, the superview of `self.searchDisplayController.searchBar` is the `UITableView`, and the second time it's still a `UIView`.

With Priya's answer, I worry about unintended consequences or unneeded overhead from re-inserting the subview *every* time the search bar is double-tapped, and I also worry about it breaking with future iOS versions. Fortunately, we can take advantage of the superview strangeness like this:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if (self.tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.superview) {
        [self.tableView insertSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar aboveSubview:self.tableView];
    }
}
```

If I had to guess what was happening, the `UISearchBar` is automatically creating a temporary `UIView` as its superview when it's active – this is the view seen when the search is being performed. While the `UISearchBar` is being dismissed, the superview gets set back to be the `UITableView` it had before, *unless* it gets dismissed so quickly that it was never properly initialized, in which case it cleans up improperly and the `UITableView` never gets the `UISearchBar` back as its child.

This solution still isn't ideal, and I think Apple must be doing something different in its own apps because their search bar UX feels a bit better. I think it would be better not to handle the second tap in the first place until the `UISearchBar` was ready. I tried using the other `UISearchBarDelegate` methods to do this, but I couldn't find an appropriate hook to override the current behavior.

Comment: Just ran into this bug myself. What if you check if `window` is nil? That way, you know it's not in the view hierarchy and you don't have to hard code the equality check.